# dbeaver redshift returning wrong data for pg_catalog schema

Tags: dbeaver

`SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_group;`

```
+---------+----------+-------------------+
| groname | grosysid |      grolist      |
+---------+----------+-------------------+
| {}      |      100 | {{101},{103},...} |
+---------+----------+-------------------+
```

Issue: For the `groname` column I get `{}` instead of the actual group name for each row, the same thing happens on the `pg_user` table. I looked in the driver settings for redshift but can't find anything that looks like it would help.

Interestingly enough, the `grolist` is also returned differently in postico on a mac ( `{101,103,...}` i.e. without the extra curly bracers).

- DBeaver Version 7.0.1.202003211804 release date march 23, 2020
- Driver: `com.amazon.redshift:redshift-jdbc42:RELEASE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.
This problem requires upgrading the DBeaver version.
Attach the contents and version of the test confirmation.

DBeaver Version Version 7.1.3.202007192031 Release date: July 20, 2020

[image]